# How can I condense my automated drop-down test case?

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, drop-down-menu, testcase

I have a test case that selects a drop-down field and then will go through every option in the dropdown. On each option I am verifying the text and on the final dropdown I am additionally verifying 2 extra fields that will be displayed. A short version of the test case looks like this:

```
messages = messages_page.Elements(self.driver)
messages.nav()
messages.advanced_search()
default = messages.advsearch_verify_received_dropdown()

if default == "Last Month":
    messages.advsearch_select_received("Custom...")
else:
    testrailFunctions.failed()

received_custom = messages.advsearch_verify_received_dropdown()
fields_revealed = messages.advsearch_verify_new_fields()

if received_custom == "Custom..." and after_and_before_revealed is True:
    testrailFunctions.passed()
else:
    testrailFunctions.failed()
```

This code in my test case only covers 2 selectable options out of 7.

Is there a better way of going about all the dropdown options in this test case? Could I construct a function or a for-loop that would select each option and verify the text and then on the final option verify the additional fields?

Any help/advice is appreciated

Answer (score 0):

I managed to create a list with all the options in a dropdown with the .options call. Then I looped through the options to grab their text. .is_enabled() also can work in the for loop as an additional verification step.

```
def advsearch_search_in_options_text_check(self):
"""Loops through all options in the drop-down"""
    dropdown = Select(self.driver.find_element(*Elements.advanced_search_in))
    return [option.text for option in dropdown.options]
```